# Strange error: Google Maps v3 and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm trying to set multiple markers using [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex) example in rails. The basic ( only HTML) version works fine.
I have a `Family` model with `latitude` and `longitude` fields as `type Float`.I'm using Mongoid.

Now In my **map.html.erb** I do (I have changed the `beaches` var to `locations`)

```
var locations = <%= @family %>;
```

In my **controller** I have:

```
def map
    @family=[[24.1411, 78.7935]]     #This works fine (shows markers)
    lat=Family.last.latitude
    lng=Family.last.longitude
    @family=[[lat,lng]]          #This doesn't work (doesn't show marker)
end
```

What is wrong here?

In both the cases the rendered `locations` var is equal to `[[24.1411, 78.7935]]` as below

[image]

I'm not using `gmaps4rails` gem because it doesn't provide reverse geocoding.

Comment: could you also paste the result without last line?

Comment: result? what you mean? For the first `@family` variable markers appear properly but not for the second `@family` variable. updated the question.

Comment: do you use gmaps4rails?

Comment: You said in a question that locations is the same in both cases, I was wondering whether you could show both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
var locations = <%= @family %>;
```

with:

```
var locations = <%= raw @family.to_json %>;
```

Comment: raw makes your string html safe so it wont be escaped

Comment: btw, why dont you use gmaps4rails?

Comment: there's no support for reverse geocoding in your gem.

Comment: :) yes but you dont need reverse geocoding to display stuff. You can add your own js wherever you need

Comment: yes I know I don't need reverse geocoding to display stuff. I can reverse geocode with the `geocoder` gem. but with me the issue is that the coordinates I've are quite close to each other such that the `geocoder` gem gives the same `address` for some coordinates. So that, in case of `gmaps4rails`, will plot markers at the same point (right?). So to avoid that I had to use the API. :)

Comment: actually no, by default, I randomize coordinates to avoid the issue you describe. You can set the random radius in options